# xcode get black window using storyboard

Tags: uiview, xcode4, storyboard

I'm trying to get a view but, when I get to it in iPhone simulator what I see is a black window and I don't now what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
subview = [[ArticulosViewController alloc]init];
subview.titulo = categoria;
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/XX/%@",[[self.listaArticulos objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] imagen]]]];
        subview.imagen = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:subview animated:YES];
```

In ArticulosViewControllew I don't have the method -(void)LoadView{}, so I'm quite lost in what I've to do

Thank you all for your help